# Reduce building size in tilemill?

Tags: tilemill, cartocss

I am designing a map of very densely populated area in Tilemill. I am using OSM building data. Due to having a lot of buildings it is very difficult to differentiate one building to another.

Is there any way to reduce all building polygon sizes to 95% or 98% so that buildings can easily be differentiate each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- simplest: remove borders at low zoom.
- shrink via carto: use `line-offset: <some small negative number>` to inset the building border and remove the `polygon-fill`, though this can create strange artifacts around corners.
- shrink via PostGIS: use `ST_Buffer(way, <negative buffer in meters>`.  See [ST_Buffer doc](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html)

Last one is probably the most robust solution, but ST_Buffer can be computationally expensive, and assumes you're pulling data in from a PostGIS database.